# how to get unusual traffic or traffic information in SoftLayer using python API's

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to know how traffic flows in SoftLayer between the servers, In course of traffic flow how to detect unusual traffic and how to detect ports that are prone to unusual/malicious traffic. Can we retrieve this information using any SoftLayer python API's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possbile using the Softlayer's API even using the Softlayer's control portal that information is not avaiable.

regards

Comment: thanks Nelson, i have tried a function using loadbalancermanager,bt still i was able to get the routing types only for a particular account.